# Fast running average during data acquisition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a piece of code which iterates through a vector several times, performs some calculation, and averages the result into existing data. This calculation is based on other variables (eg time) as well as the input, so the same input has a different output and the total results cannot be pre-computed. This looks like this:

```
output = np.zeros(50)
while loop_count < max_loops:
    for idx, dat in enumerate(vec):
        val = calculate(dat)
        averaged = (val + output[idx] * loop_count) / (1 + loop_count)
        output[idx] = averaged
    loop_count += 1
```

This works fine but appears to be quite slow (taking around 9s). Is there a better solution, ideally using numpy, scipy or pandas? The length of vec can be quite long so avoiding a copy is also ideal

Comment: if this takes around 9 s then I assume that about 95 % of this time is spend in `calculate` as the looping and averaging, even for a longer vector, wouldn't be so expensive. So I guess there's nothing to do here except trying to optimize the calculation itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just compute the sum and divide by `max_loops` in the end, right? This would make it one bit faster as you also could do the summation in-place:

```
output = np.zeros(50)
for idx, dat in enumerate(vec):
    for count in range(max_loop):
        output[idx] += calculate(dat)
    output[idx] /= max_loop
```

As you provided a more abstract example (which is helpful), I am not sure whether this restructured version works for your application. If the computation in `calculate` is truly independent for the various repetitions, I don't see further simplification.